# highstock with json data

Tags: json, highcharts

I want use highstock to show my data in the web ，but i have someproblem with the json data，
the Example of basic-line  :http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/
i change  the javascript file the

```
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?',  function(data)
```

to the

```
$.getJSON('data.json',  function(data)
```

i want use the json data in my web folder and i put data in the json file like :

```
[[1143072000000,60.16],

[1143158400000,59.96],
[1143417600000,59.51],
[1143504000000,58.71],
[1143590400000,62.33],
[1143676800000,62.75],
[1143763200000,62.72],

/* Apr 2006 */
[1144022400000,62.65],
[1144108800000,61.17],
[1144195200000,67.21],
[1144281600000,71.24]]
```

but i can see nothing in my web,  what is wrong with me?  is it the json data Format wrong？or others  thanks for give me some help

Answer (score 0):

In case when you use JSON, then you should get rid of all comments.

So JSON should looks like:

```
[[1143072000000,60.16],
[1143158400000,59.96],
[1143417600000,59.51],
[1143504000000,58.71],
[1143590400000,62.33],
[1143676800000,62.75],
[1143763200000,62.72],
[1144022400000,62.65],
[1144108800000,61.17],
[1144195200000,67.21],
[1144281600000,71.24]]
```

and chart code:

```
 $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {

    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename your file to data.js . For javascript file and not JSON. It's like that for me :)